# Python: Iterate through a list by value, not by index

Tags: python

How can I iterate through by something other than the index?

I have

```
L = [[1,2,3],[5,3,6],[5,4,14],[23,5,2],....,[11,13,6]]
```

notice how the middle element is increasing always by 1. the outer elements are pretty much random.

I want to be able to say something like this:

```
for i in L[2:4]:
```

which would iterate through the elements: [1,2,3],[5,3,6],[5,4,14], as opposed to looking at 2:4 as indexes.

so obviously the syntax of my for loop is incorrect. How can I do this?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: perhaps this is correct. I am not sure what you mean though. Can you put it in an answer and apply it the list I gave?

Comment: I assume these columns have meaningful names, then? If so, in pandas this would be `df[2 <= df['col2'] <= 4]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[item for item in L if 2 <= item[1] <= 4]
```

is one way of doing it

```
def slice_special(a_list,slice_idx,minimum_value,maximum_value):
     return [item for item in a_list if minimum_value <= item[slice_idx] <= maximum_value]

print slice_special(L,1,2,4)
```

or something more sophisticated like a dedicated data structure

```
class MyDataStructure:
    def __init__(self,a_list):
        self.my_data = a_list
    def __getitem__(self,arg):
        if isinstance(arg,slice):
            return [item for item in self.my_data if arg.start <= item[arg.step] <= arg.stop]

        raise Exception("%s is unscriptable"%self)

print MyDataStructure([[1,2,3],[5,3,6],[5,4,14],[23,5,2]])[2:4:1]
```

Comment: in for loop form, can I do:: for item in L if 2 <= item[1] <= 4:

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the elements of the list, you can unpack the sublists into the iteration variables:

```
>>> L = [[1,2,3],[5,3,6],[5,4,14],[23,5,2]]
>>> for a, b, c in L:
...     print(a,b,c)
...
1 2 3
5 3 6
5 4 14
23 5 2
>>>
```

If you don't want to use a certain index, you can assign it to `_`, which is the standard way of notating unused variables.